# What does alpha mean in plotting color attribute in R?

Tags: r

I have the following code line:

```
  plot(reducedDims(seLX_MET)$UMAP[shuffle, ], asp = 1, pch = 16, xlab = "UMAP-1", ylab = "UMAP-2", 
       col = alpha(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)[factor(colData(seLX_MET)$cell_type)][shuffle], alpha = .5))
```

it is plotting for slingshot object (library slingshot). Although this is a specific bioinformatics tool, I think the color choice should be something common in plotting functions.

The problem is, whenever I try to increase the numbers in *col = alpha(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)* from 6 to 12 => *alpha(c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)* it repeats the colors on the plot.
[image]
But *factor(colData(seLX_MET)$cell_type)* has 12 levels.

The output of this piece

```
alpha(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)[factor(colData(seLX_MET)$cell_type)][shuffle], alpha = .5)
```

is a list of color codes for each point.

So, my questions are:

- what is the first alpha in this case? (I think the second alpha is transparency)
- How to avoid color duplication in this case?

Comment: What libraries are you using, I imagine this is `scales::alpha` (Modify colour transparency)
The first alpha is a function, the second is a parameter within that function

Comment: the library is called slingshot, so the function is slingshot::plot

Comment: I'm not overly sure on this but that looks to import `RColorBrewer` which in turn then uses `scales`.

Answer (score 1):

Although I still did not understand the role of *alpha* in this function, I ended up using RColorBrewer which gave me decent colors:

```
plot(reducedDims(seLX_MET)$UMAP[shuffle, ], asp = 1, pch = 16, xlab = "UMAP-1", ylab = "UMAP-2", 
 col = alpha(brewer.pal(12,"Paired")[factor(colData(seLX_MET)$cell_type)][shuffle], alpha = .5))
```